# Python not finding modules after changing permissions on Windows

Tags: python, windows, module, permissions

I recently got a new PC, and was messing around with Python. I tried editing a module in the Site Packages folder, and needed to change permission on the Python folder to do so. However, after doing this, whenever I try to import a module, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`. I check the `sys.path` list, and the path is still in there. Any suggestions as to what I could change to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can always uninstall and reinstall Python.
Also make sure you are running your computer as an admin.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because some of the installation packages have already left in your home directory which you tried to install python from there. They are n the form of '.package' (e.g. '.matplotlib') and as they left in the home directory python first goes there when you call the package which needs permission. You need to delete them (the ones that are NOT in the python directory!). And then each time that you call the package, Python will search for at your given PATH.